# Mojave 59 second hang

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, mojave

About two weeks ago, my Mac started hanging on boot.  It has been driving me crazy.
Today I looked at the logs in `/var/logs/system.log` and on every boot I can see a 59 - 60 second hang, exactly.  And it's always the same line

```
Oct 10 18:19:44 FOO-BAR ControlStrip[226]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: dispatch source activated with no event handler set; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
Oct 10 18:20:44 FOO-BAR loginwindow[93]: There are still active callers
```

The fact it is so precise makes me think some process is timing out and the Mac just decides to continue.

Is there a way to identify what that could be?  Nothing above there really looks bad?

Edit: new info: I created another account and that account does not hang.

Comment: reset the control strip `pkill "Touch Bar agent";`
`killall "ControlStrip";`  you might have to use sudo

Comment: No dice :( still hangs. But I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: so what app do you have in your account that would do that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Little Snitch installed, then you need to make sure you update to the latest version, because there was an older version that caused a pause on boot, just as you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some other app competing with Mojave for the Touch Bar.

Simply try to reset it for now, and if it continues disable that 3D party app.

In Terminal use

```
pkill "Touch Bar agent"
```

then

```
killall "ControlStrip"
```

that should reset it.

If creating new user account solves the problem it is definitely some 3D party app in you account.

Comment: I am not smart enough to disagree, but what makes you think it is the touch bar?

Comment: so I made a mistake ? you do not have Touch Bar ? AFIK the only thing in Apple lingo for ControlStrip refers to Touch bar.

Comment: Oh I get it! I’m sorry, was merely copying the last line before the hang and the first line after.